# Error loading 'Module'

Tags: webpack

I'm bundling a typescript project, and webpack fails with the error

`ERROR in (webpack)/lib/NormalModule.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'module' in 'C:\SPA\MyApp\node_modules\webpack\lib'
 @ (webpack)/lib/NormalModule.js 91:16-33`

If I hack the module from 

`var Module = require("module");`

to 

`var Module = require("./module");`
 
the problem is resolved.

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this to be an issue? It seems odd that nobody else is reporting this as an issue.
The line in question is here:
https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/lib/NormalModule.js#L90

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I vaguely remember it was resolved by a subsequent patch in WebPack.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the right path is configured in `resolve.modules` array.

For this file:

a/b/c/d/file.js

You'll need in your webpack.config.js:

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js'],
    modules: ['./a/b/c']
}
```

Webpack will try to resolve your absolute imports againts those paths + node_modules.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

```
NormalModule.js Module not found: Can't resolve 'module'
```

After trying absolutely everything, finally I had to:

- delete node_modules folder
- run npm cache verify
- **revert package-lock.json** to the last one commited, when the app worked. (Not just delete the file, but **revert**)
- npm install

I hope this helps someone :)

Thanks!